# UTF-8 encoding of unicodes in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I was a bit confused about different types of encoding, but there are really good answers on stackoverflow to clarify that. Still I have one doubt -

Whenever you use C++ and write to a file using ofstream, does it encodes the unicode string to utf-8 by default. And to mention whether something is a unicode character, I have to use something like '\u0444', but I never do this for my english strings. So rather than writing 'a', I should have written '\u0061'. Does that mean , C++ automatically converts english alphabets to their unicode formats. And How about string data structure, are they also stored in variables in UTF-8 encoding format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The stream classes doesn't do any encoding or decoding at all, they just write what you tell them to write. It's up to you to enforce encodings.

Comment: So do they write in ascii format or what ? If I do file >> "stackoverflow" , does it write that to file in order such as ascii value of s , ascii value of t, ascii value of a ... and so on.

Comment: @ShubhamJain Most probably it's ASCII, but finally that's OS dependent.

Comment: But if I do something like this char b = '\u0444' , how is it going to save that, there is no ascii representation for that unicode.

Comment: Then it would write two bytes, `0x04` followed by `0x44`. How those two bytes are interpreted by any programs reading the file isn't the something the stream classes do, it's the programs themselves.

Comment: But that is bad right. If later on I want to convert this stream to UTF-8, how is it going to know that these two bytes represent one character.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that the stream don't know that, but ***you*** do. Your ***program*** knows it, and can interpret it properly, and change encoding if the program wanted to. The purpose of the streams is to write or read a stream of bytes without discrimination and without processing. How that stream is interpreted is something your program handles, not the streams themselves.

Comment: Unix based systems use UTF8, and `a` is just `a` in UTF8. Windows uses UTF16, where `a` is represented in bytes. `'\u0061'` looks like UTF16 encoding.

Comment: Thanks Joachim for clarification. That means our program itself has to encode the string before passing it to file output stream and if we fail to do so, we will never be able to read it.

Comment: @Barmak do you mean that file output stream is by default written in UTF-8 format in Unix Systems and in UTF-16 format in Windows system.

Comment: No, I mean for example Unix based systems understand `printf(u8"ελληνική\n");` (this is UTF-8) but Windows will understand `printf(L"ελληνική\n");` (this is UTF-16). When you write to a file, you have to pick either UTF-8 or UTF-16 and write the output. As mentioned earlier this is operating system dependent. In Windows you may decide to convert your UTF-16 string and write it as UTF-8 for the sake of compatibility.